# Two methods from UserDefaults.standard

Tags: swift, uikit

everybody, tell me by UserDefaults class, methods: 1)

```
open func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

and 2)

```
open func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)
```

Identical? Just one added as an extension to NSObject, and the other in UserDefaults itself, which is inherited from NSObject?

Comment: Thank you! I got a response on my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one which is on the `NSObject` seems to be a KVC (key value coding) method and does not have any relation to `NSUserDefaults`. So you need the second one when working with `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Thank you! I got a response on my question!

Answer (score 0):

From `NSObject` (You can't use it for saving/reading)

```
open func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
```

From defaults (You can use it for saving/reading)

```
open func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)
```

After you select one from menu , Write click in function name and click **Jump tp Definition** you will be directed to it's class

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)` is for [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/nskeyvaluecoding), which is implemented by any `NSObject`.

`func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)` is specific to `UserDefaults` and is used to store values in the defaults database.